# Одномерный или двумерный массив?

Tags: массивы, php

Допустим, у меня есть такой массив:

```
$arr = array();
```

и такой

```
$mas = array("g"=>"minsk","c"=>"gomel");
```

При таком присваивании

```
$arr[] = $mas;
```

получается двумерный массив или все таки одномерный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двумерный, конечно. Вы в массив записываете массив. Будет

```
$arr=array('0'=>array("g"=>"minsk","c"=>"gomel"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Ведь это легко посмотреть самому:

```
print_r($arr);
```

выдаст

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [g] => minsk [c] => gomel ) )